# Python Script to Copy S3 contents encrypted through client side KMS Key between S3 buckets

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case where I need to copy contents between S3 buckets. The catch is that the S3 bucket where the contents lie are encrypted through a CMK KMS key and I need to decrypt it using a different CMK KMS key before storing it in another bucket.

I tried to first fetch the file from S3, and then decrypt it using the KMS key

```py
import boto3

source_bucket = "sourceBucket"
destination_bucket = "destinationBucket"
source_kms_key_id = "kmsKey"
dest_kms_key_id = "destKmsKeyId"

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
kms_client = boto3.client('kms', region_name='us-west-2')


def get_files_from_s3(bucket_name,destination_bucket,kms_key_id):
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name)
    if 'Contents' in response:
        objects = response['Contents']
        for obj in objects:
            file_key = obj['Key']
            file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
            encrypted_data = file_object['Body'].read()
            hello = str(encrypted_data)
            # print(f"Encrypted Data: {encrypted_data}")
            print("aa")
            decrypted_data = kms_client.decrypt(CiphertextBlob=encrypted_data, KeyId=kms_key_id)['Plaintext']
            s3_client.put_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=file_key, Body=decrypted_data)
            print(f"File key: {file_key}")



get_files_from_s3(source_bucket,destination_bucket,kms_key_id)
```

but this throws an error

```py
1 validation error detected: Value at 'ciphertextBlob' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 6144 (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 68c37cf6-0f1a-405c-9bf2-72f0d43c45ee; Proxy: null)
```

In Java, I was able to achieve the same using the following S3 client

```java
public AmazonS3 getS3Client(@NonNull final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration) {
    final String awsRegion = region().toString();
    final com.amazonaws.regions.Region kmsRegion = RegionUtils.getRegion(awsRegion);
    final CryptoConfiguration cryptoConfiguration = new CryptoConfiguration()
            .withAwsKmsRegion(kmsRegion);
    final KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider materialsProvider = new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(getS3KmsId());

    return AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCryptoConfiguration(cryptoConfiguration)
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration)
            .withEncryptionMaterials(materialsProvider)
            .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
            .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
            .build();
}
```

I wonder if there's any similar/other solution available to this problem?

TIA

Comment: This might help https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/kms-example-encrypt-decrypt-file.html It seems like `decrypted_data = kms_client.decrypt` is for `Decrypt a data key` which is then used to decrypt the file.

Comment: You are also using `hello = str(encrypted_data)`, but that is not the same as `hello = encrypted_data.decode()`

Comment: @David Already tried. Code snippet that I provided uses this method only and it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you do not just have SSE and do not need to worry about manually decrypting any data??

Comment: @C.Nivs will large files work with .decode()

Comment: @luk2302 yes I am sure about that. I have a Java codebase in place which performs that operation

Comment: @C.Nivs tried with `.decode()` got this error:- `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 0: invalid continuation byte`

Answer (score 0):

As S3 objects were encrypted with the S3 Encryption Client (S3EC). There is no Python implementation for the S3 Encryption Client.

I need to use Java or another supported language.

[Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-s3-encryption-client/latest/developerguide/what-is-s3-encryption-client.html?t=7).